# problema con tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, vscode

Soy principiante en python y al ejecutar un programa en tkinter que sé que está bien escrito me sale esto en la terminal de visual studio code: ImportError: cannot import name 'ttk' from partially initialized module 'tkinter' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: Bienvenido! Por favor agrega tu código, así podremos ayudarte. Te recomiendo que leas también [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). :)

Answer (score 0):

la verdad, para darte una respuesta precisa necesito ver tu código, ese error se puede dar por muchos motivos, lo que te puedo decir son las formas correctas de importar la librería tkinter:

forma 1: from tkinter import* (Para importar toda la librería)

froma 2: from tkinter import función (Si quieres importar solamente una función)

froma 3: import tkinter as tk (Estas importando una librería pero con un alías) Es una manera de importar que es usada en programas muy largos.

Te recomiendo las primeras dos formas (sobre todo la 1ra porque te importa todo y evita errores ), si el error no es por eso entonces edita tu post y añade tu código, así puedo saber con exactitud a que se debe.

CORDIALMENTE,

LUCIO J